# WooCommerce replaces products in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I can only add one product to the cart. So whenever a new product is added old one is gone from the cart.

Just can't figure out any reason for this. I've disabled the theme/woocommerce folder but still the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried to deactivate your plugings? Probably a plugin is doing the replacing.

Comment: Maybe you set some option that these products can't be bought together.

Comment: just check activating with storefront theme